# Disable future dates in Formly Datepicker in Angular

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, angular-formly

I am using Formly with Material in Angular and have a datepicker. All I want to do is disable future dates so they cannot be selected when selecting a date, I can't seem to find anything online!

```
export class AppComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({});
  model: any = {};
  options: FormlyFormOptions = {};
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'Datepicker',
      type: 'datepicker',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Datepicker',
        placeholder: 'Placeholder',
        description: 'Description',
        required: true,
        //what to put here to disable future dates?
      },
    },
  ];
}
```

You can play around with the code here:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/gkyxqxygybo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I found [here](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-material/blob/master/docs/types/datepicker.md) that I can use ```maxDate``` but when I add ```date = new Date();``` above where form is declared and then ```maxDate```: this.date, it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I finally found the answer [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dyn-max-date). I needed to add

```
datepickerOptions: {
  max: new Date(),
},
```

to the template options.

Comment: works for material but not primeNg